# How to specify index start point in CSV in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a python script that generates a CSV file for me. The script adds an index column to the CSV that rightfully starts at 0 and goes onto the last row. This works as expected. However, I need to find a way to make sure that the index starts from the last index number in the previously generated CSV file. That is, if I have the following CSV:

csv1.csv

```
,Name,Customer
0,test1,customer1
1,test2,customer2
```

I would like the next CSV file generated to read:

csv2.csv

```
,Name,Customer
2,test1,customer1
3,test2,customer2
```

I suspect we will need to import the last generated file to read the last index on it, but how do I make the new CSV file generated start from that point?

Note: I do not wish to import data from the previously generated CSV. I simply want to have the new index start from where the last index ended.

Below is my script thus far, as a reference.

```
by_name = {}
with open('flavor.csv') as b:
    for row in csv.DictReader(b):
        name = row.pop('Name')
        by_name[name] = row

with open('output.csv', 'w') as c:
    w = csv.DictWriter(c, ['ID', 'Name', 'Flavor', 'RAM', 'Disk', 'Ephemeral', 'VCPUs', 'Customer', 'Misc', 'date_stamp', 'Month', 'Year','Unixtime'])
    w.writeheader()

    with open('instance.csv') as a:
        for row in csv.DictReader(a):
            try:
                match = by_name[row['Flavor']]
            except KeyError:
                continue

            row.update(match)

            w.writerow(row)

df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
df[['Customer','Misc']] = df.Name.str.split('-', n=1,expand=True)
df[['date_stamp']] = date_time
df[['Month']] = month
df[['Year']] = year
df[['Unixtime']] = unixtime
df.loc[df.Misc.str.startswith('business', na=False),'Customer']+='-business'
df.Misc=df.Misc.str.strip('business-')
df[['Customer']] = df.Customer.str.title()
df.to_csv('final-output.csv')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to index a pandas data frame starting at n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515644/how-to-index-a-pandas-data-frame-starting-at-n)

Comment: Read previous df `old_df` then genarate `new_df` and then set index for new df like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47516706/6075699) given `new_df.index = new_df.index + len(old_df)`